# How can I get result in celery when celery worker is running on a different server using AsyncResult

Tags: celery

I am sending task to celery worker which is running on a remote server using the following code from lets say server A

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult

redis_url = os.getenv("REDIS_ENDPOINT")
app = Celery("tasks", backend=f"redis://{redis_url}", broker=f"redis://{redis_url}")

def send(...):
  result = app.send_task("mytask_name", ...)
  return result.id

def receive(...):
  result = AsyncResult(id=task_id, app=app)
  
  return result.ready() ? result.get() : ""
```

Method send will send task to worker which is running on remote server, lets say server B. My issue is with the receive method, AsyncResult doesn't seem to work for me.    The reason I am not storing the result Object that I get after sending the task is in a case where server A is distributed as well. The send and receive might not get called on the same server. Is there a way to get the results using celery in this type of setup?

Comment: This should work. Did you try to just call `return result.get()` ?

Comment: @DejanLekic when I call result.get() in send method it works, but I want the method send to not wait until the results return for long running processes. With the above implementation I get an error from method in celery backend implementation, get_key_for_task, where it is looking for an object but getting UUID, I decided to use redis client to get meta data directly from the queue. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: AsyncResult.ready() returns immediately True or False. (Quote: _Return True if the task has executed. If the task is still running, pending, or is waiting for retry then False is returned._). Are you trying to say that calling receive() after some long period of time still returns an empty string?

Comment: AsyncResult.ready() throws an exception
```bash
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 856, in get_key_for_task
app_1            |     return key_t('').join([
app_1            | TypeError: sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, UUID found
```